# how to edit an existing reminder in an array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an array of reminders(reminder model) in a view model and want to be able to edit existing reminders specifically through and edit swipe action and then through the reminders detail screen. I tried adding a button with a sheet to my Homeview in a list and then tried updating the edited reminder in the reminders array to a property in my view model called existingRemindData by using an update function in the reminder model. this should work but the remind var created by the foreach loop in the home view doesn't keep its value when it is called in the sheet. In the home view under the edit swipe action when I assign homevm.existingRemindData = remind.data it is equal to whatever reminder I swipe on because I did a print statement to confirm but as soon as I try to use the remind var inside of the sheet for the edit action the remind var defaults to the first item in the reminder array in the view model which is obviously not right. how would I make it so it uses the correct reminder index value when trying to update the reminder or is there another way which I could implement this functionality. any help would be great and look in the code for clarification on what I talk about.

HomeView

'''

```
import SwiftUI

struct HomeView: View {
@StateObject private var homeVM = HomeViewModel()
@State var percent: Int = 1
@State var showDetailEditView = false
@State var showAddView = false
@State var dropDown = false

//@State var filter = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach($homeVM.reminds) { $remind in
                    ReminderView(remind: $remind)
                        //.background(remind.theme.mainColor)
                        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0))
                        .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.showDetailEditView.toggle()
                                homeVM.existingRemindData = remind.data
                                print(homeVM.existingRemindData.title)
                            }) {
                                Label("Edit", systemImage: "pencil")
                            }
                        }
                        .sheet(isPresented: $showDetailEditView) {
                            NavigationView {
                                ReminderEditView(data: $homeVM.existingRemindData)
                                    .navigationTitle(homeVM.existingRemindData.title)
                                    .toolbar {
                                        ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                                            Button("Cancel") {
                                                self.showDetailEditView.toggle()
                                                homeVM.existingRemindData = Reminder.Data()
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                                            Button("Done") {
                                                self.showDetailEditView.toggle()
                                                print("\(remind.id) \(remind.title)")
                                                print("\(homeVM.existingRemindData.id) \(homeVM.existingRemindData.title)")
                                                remind.update(from: homeVM.existingRemindData)
                                                homeVM.newRemindData = Reminder.Data()
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [
                                        Color(UIColor(red: 0.376, green: 0.627, blue: 0.420, alpha: 1)),
                                        Color(UIColor(red: 0.722, green: 0.808, blue: 0.725, alpha: 1))
                                    ]), startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
                            }
                        }
                        .swipeActions(allowsFullSwipe: true) {
                            Button (role: .destructive, action: {
                                homeVM.deleteReminder(remind: remind)
                            }) {
                                Label("Delete", systemImage: "trash.fill")
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .onAppear(
                perform: {
                    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
                    UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
                })
```

'''

Reminder edit view

'''

```
import SwiftUI

extension Binding {
static func ??(lhs: Binding<Optional<Value>>, rhs: Value) -> Binding<Value> {
    return Binding(get: {lhs.wrappedValue ?? rhs}, set: {lhs.wrappedValue = $0})
}
}

struct ReminderEditView: View {
@ObservedObject var editVM: EditViewModel

init(data: Binding<Reminder.Data>) {
    editVM = EditViewModel(data: data)
}

var body: some View {
    Form {
        Section {
            TextField("Title", text: $editVM.data.title)
            TextField("Notes", text: $editVM.data.notes ?? "")
                .frame(height: 100, alignment: .top)
        }
        Section {
            Toggle(isOn: $editVM.data.hasDueDate, label: {
                if editVM.data.hasDueDate {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("Date")
                        Text(editVM.data.hasDueDate ? editVM.data.formatDate(date: editVM.data.date!) : "\(editVM.data.formatDate(date: Date.now))")
                            .font(.caption)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                } else {
                    Text("Date")
                }
            })
            if editVM.data.hasDueDate {
                DatePicker("Date", selection: $editVM.data.dueDate, in: Date()..., displayedComponents: .date)
                    .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
                    
            }
```

'''

Reminder model

'''

```
extension Reminder {
struct Data: Identifiable {
    var title: String = ""
    var notes: String?
    var date: Date?
    var time: Date?
    var theme: Theme = .poppy
    var iscomplete: Bool = false
    var priority: RemindPriority = .None
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    
    var dueDate: Date {
        get {
            return date ?? Date()
        }
        set {
            date = newValue
        }
    }
    
    var dueTime: Date {
        get {
            return time ?? Date()
        }
        set {
            time = newValue
        }
    }
    
    func formatDate(date: Date) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .full
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        
        return formatter.string(from: date)
    }
    
    func formatTime(time: Date) -> String {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .none
        formatter.timeStyle = .short
        
        return formatter.string(from: time)
    }
    
    var hasDueDate: Bool {
      get {
        date != nil
      }
      set {
        if newValue == true {
          date = Date()
        }
        else {
          date = nil
            hasDueTime = false
        }
      }
    }
    
    var hasDueTime: Bool {
      get {
        time != nil
      }
      set {
        if newValue == true {
          time = Date()
          hasDueDate = true
        }
        else {
          time = nil
        }
      }
    }
}

 var data: Data {
    Data(title: title, notes: notes, date: date, time: time, theme: theme, iscomplete: iscomplete, priority: priority)
}

mutating func update(from data: Data) {
    title = data.title
    notes = data.notes
    date = data.date
    time = data.time
    theme = data.theme
    iscomplete = data.iscomplete
    priority = data.priority
}


init(data: Data) {
    title = data.title
    notes = data.notes
    date = data.date
    time = data.time
    theme = data.theme
    iscomplete = data.iscomplete
    priority = data.priority
    id = data.id
}
}
```

'''

HomeViewModel(View model talked about)

'''

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var reminds: [Reminder] = Reminder.sampleReminders
@Published var newRemindData = Reminder.Data()
@Published var existingRemindData = Reminder.Data()
@Published var selectedRemind = Reminder(data: Reminder.Data())
@Published var compReminds: [Reminder] = []

private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

/*init(reminds: [Reminder]) {
    self.reminds = reminds
}*/

func newReminder() {
    let newRemind = Reminder(data: newRemindData)
    reminds.append(newRemind)
    newRemindData = Reminder.Data()
}

func deleteReminder(remind: Reminder) {
    Just(remind)
        .delay(for: .seconds(0.25), scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        .sink {remind in
            if remind.iscomplete {
                self.removeRemind(remind: remind)
            }
            if !remind.iscomplete {
                
                self.removeRemind(remind: remind)
            }
            self.reminds.removeAll { $0.id == remind.id }
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}

func appendRemind(complete: Reminder) {
    compReminds.append(complete)
}

func removeRemind(remind: Reminder) {
    compReminds.removeAll() { $0.id == remind.id }
}

func remindIndex() -> Int {
    return reminds.firstIndex(where: {
        $0.id == existingRemindData.id
    }) ?? 1
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

We don't use view model objects in SwiftUI. Change EditViewModel class to be an EditConfig struct, declare it as `@State var config: EditConfig?` use it as the item in [`sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/form/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)) instead of the bool version.

Also, your date formatting is not SwiftUI compatible, you won't benefit from the labels being updated automatically when the user changes their region settings. To fix that remove the formatDate code and instead supply the formatter to Text or simply use .date. If using a formatter object make sure you aren't initing a new one every time, e.g. store one inside an @State struct or a static var. in SwiftUI we must not init objects in a View's init and body, only value types.